# QBXML Version not supported Error

Tags: c#, quickbooks

I am using QB 12 and I use RSS Bus to integrate quickbooks with my project.

While inserting `BillPaymentCheck` I am getting error as QBXML Version not supported.

If you look at this link, it says QBXML version 6 or higher is supported.

I changed the version to 6, but that did not work.

Below is my code for more details:

```
foreach (DAL.ACHTransaction dalTransaction in lstTransactions)
            {
                string PayeeId = dbCntxt.TechnicianBillingRecords.Where(c => c.BillId == dalTransaction.BillId).FirstOrDefault().TechnicianBilling.TechnicianTripDetail.Technician.QBId;
                QuickBooks qbCntxt = new QuickBooks();
                Bill qbBill = qbCntxt.Bills.Where(c => c.ID == dalTransaction.BillId).FirstOrDefault();
                BillPaymentCheck billCheck = new BillPaymentCheck();

                string bankAccntId = dbCntxt.Configurations.Where(c => c.ConfigKey == "BankId").FirstOrDefault().ConfigValues;


                billCheck.Amount = dalTransaction.Amount;
                billCheck.PayeeId = PayeeId;
                billCheck.ReferenceNumber = "ACH";
                billCheck.BankAccountId = bankAccntId;
                string appliedTo = "<BillPaymentChecksAppliedTo><Row><AppliedToRefId>" + dalTransaction.BillId + "</AppliedToRefId><AppliedToAmount>" + dalTransaction.Amount.ToString() + "</AppliedToAmount></Row></BillPaymentChecksAppliedTo>";
                billCheck.AppliedToAggregate = appliedTo;
                qbCntxt.AddToBillPaymentChecks(billCheck);
                qbBill.IsPaid = 1;
                qbCntxt.SaveChanges();
                dalTransaction.IsProccessedInQB = true;
                dbCntxt.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks,
Dhaval Shukla

Comment: What year/version of QuickBooks are you using? You also didn't post a link. Where are you setting the qbXML version?

Comment: I am using QB 12.0, can you advise how to set QBXML Version?

Comment: http://www.rssbus.com/kb/help/rqr1-a/RSBQuickBooks_p_QBXMLVersion.rst

Answer (score 0):

I don't know RSS Bus, so this may not be the case, but there are some features within a transaction that require a higher level than just the base transaction. For example, A BillPaymentCheckAdd at minimum requires version 2, but if you are using the Memo field, you need at least version 3. If you are using ExchangeRate you need at least version 8, ExternalGUID needs 9, DiscountAmount needs 10, and DiscountClassRef needs 11.

If you set your version to be version 11, which is the highest of all the components of a BillPaymentCheckAdd, and the error goes away, then the RSS Bus may be setting one of these fields internally that you're not specifying, causing it to require a higher version of QBXML.

Comment: How can I Set QBXML Version in Quickbooks?

Comment: I don't use RSS Bus, so not 100% sure, but it looks like from their [documentation](http://www.rssbus.com/kb/help/RQR4-A/Connection.rst) you can set the version in your connection string . Include "QBXMLVersion=11.0;" in your string somewhere should work.